# Asrock X79 Extreme 11

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I build a pc with the following parts:

```
 Asrock x79 Extreme 11
 Intel i7 4930K
 Corsair DDR3 1866MHz 32GB
```

When I try to boot the PC all fans start to spinning but Dr. Debug shows 00 and all USB and display devices are dead. It doesn't do a memory check or something... What can I do?

Comment: Did you connected CPU power connector on the mothrboard? What power supply you are using? What's your VGA?

Comment: A Chieftex 650. The Motherboard requires 2 8-Pin 12V Connectors and one 24-Pin Connector. Both are connected. VGA: Geforce GTX 285.

Comment: Ok, both 6-pin VGA supplementary power connectors are plugged tight I suppose

Comment: Ok, now I payed attention. The 00 Dr. Debug code means that your CPU  isn't initialised. So this could mean that CPU isn't installed properly, PSU does not supply 12V on 8-pin connector or the motherboard power regulation have some issue. Although, you can try to clear CMOS. Sometimes it helps

Comment: I checked the CPU a minute ago: The colored triangle is aligend with the colored triangle ond sockel frame thing. I checked if I could install the CPU wrong, it's not possible without much force. How can I reset the CMOS?

Comment: I removed the VGA Card to test if the display of dr debug changes - but it hasn't...

Comment: Plug out your power cord, pres the power button for 10-15 seconds to drain your MB's capacitors. On the rear panel, next to the PS/2 connector, you have the clr CMOS button. Press it and hold for at least 10-15 seconds. Then turn on computer. If you have a multimeter check the voltage on 8-pin connectors. It should be 12V ±5%. It is possible that you have higher than allowed voltage drop under the load if your PSU have some issue. So voltage should be between 11.4V and 12.6V

Comment: I reseted the CMOS but no change: 00. I do not have a multimeter. Is there a other way? I guesss it boils down to: broken MB, broken CPU, broken PSU (all three components are new... )-: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what you have in the comments, check your BIOS version. For your CPU you must have BIOS **3.00** version, while initial version was **1.10**. You can find the BIOS version on your MB's box label. If you have older BIOS version, than maybe you will have to find the older Sandy Bridge CPU to be able to flash a newer BIOS. BIOS v**3.00** was released this summer to support Ivy Bridge CPUs.

In case that you cannot find the CPU, maybe the ASROCK service near you can do that for you. Just a solution you should check before you start to think about faulty components :(

Comment: I found a sticker on the MB with the following text: p2.80-15B I guess this is the version of the bios?

Comment: No. You should have the sticker on the side of the motherboard cardboard. Usually you can find there the serial number,the product number, model, bunch of bar codes and there should be the version of the BIOS

Comment: Serial No: 35<somestuff>03O280, Part No: 90-MXGKK0-A0UAYZ <newline> X79 Extreme 11/A/ASR The rest are barcodes and a good old "Made in China".

Comment: Got it, theres a page for that kind of problem: http://www.asrock.com/support/index.asp?cat=FindBIOS so p2.80 is the bios version.

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry. Yes, your sticker is the BIOS version (2.80). So you should flash with 3.00 BIOS revision

Comment: No problem thanks a lot for your input. I will contact the store I bought the MB I hope they can update it.